# c++ select() decrement file descriptor count

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, select, tcp

Here's the situation:

The fd_set is created and initialized:

```
fd_set readset;                       //fd_set named readset
FD_ZERO(&readset);                    //clearing fd_set
FD_SET(listen_socket, &readset);      //adding a listening socket to readset

/*use for timeout*/
timeval blocktime;
blocktime.tv_sec=0;
blocktime.tv_usec=0;
```

Right now, the current values show that `listen_socket` is added to readset:

```
readset.fd_count = 1
readset.fd_array[0] = 116
```

The problem occurs at this instruction:

> int err = select (0x7FFFFFFF, &readset, NULL, NULL, &blocktime);

I expect `select()` would return a value of 1, since I added one listening socket to readset. Instead, `select()` returns 0 and the value of readset.fd_count is decremented by one.

The new values are:

> ```
> readset.fd_count = 0
> readset.fd_array[0] = 116
> ```

I can't find what's going on here. I am programming on Windows 7. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `select()` updates the provided `fd_set` record(s) to indicate which socket(s) satisfy the requested state(s).  A return value of >0 means one or more socket(s) were satisfied, 0 means a timeout occurred and no socket(s) were satisfied within the specified timeout period, and -1 means error.  You are using a timeout of 0, so your read `fd_set` gets cleared if the socket is not immediately readable.

BTW, the first parameter of `select()` is not used on Windows and should be set to 0.

Answer (score 2):

You passed in a valid timeout of zero time. It correctly updated your read set to tell you that, in the zero time allowed, zero sockets in your read set had readable data.

Three Options:

- Give it a longer timeout, so it has a chance to find something to do
- Loop until it updates your readset to indicate something has readable data
- Set the timeout parameter to null to block indefinitely

You may want to combine #1 and #2 there, but that depends on your use case.